# Symfony2, Doctrine2, updating entity

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I want to update an entity into the db with an ajax call to the controller. However, I only know how to update entity using Symfony's form. Currently I have a form that will be appended by a jQuery method and submit it through ajax but am lost at what to do in the controller.

Ajax:

```
$("#editctrno").on("submit", function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();

     $.ajax({
         url: "{{ path('containers_edit') }}",
         type: "POST",
         data: {'ctrno' : $("#ctrno").val(),
                'refno' : $("#refno").val()},
         dataType: "json",
         success: function(data) {
             console.log(data[0].ctrno);
         }
   });
});
```

Now on my controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/edit/", name="containers_edit", defaults={"_format" = "json"})
 */
public function editCtr(Request $request) {
    $ctrno = $request->get('ctrno');
    $refno =  $request->get('refno');

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('Bundle:Ref');

    // I want to access in the database to find the 'refno' and update the 'ctrno', 
    // something like:
    // $entity = $em->findRefno($refno);
    // $entity->setCtrno($ctrno);
    // $em->flush();

    return new Response(json_encode($entity));
}
```

Any suggestions for this?

Comment: Do like there is normal form, just don't forget to Serialize data in jQuery.

Comment: take a look here - http://codemonkeys.be/2013/01/ajaxify-your-symfony2-forms-with-jquery/

Comment: what exactly does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Check the link in the comment by [dmnptr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1712898/dmnptr) it has everything you need.

Just one thing to add, in your code you'll need to change the method name from

`editCtr()` to `editCtrAction()`

all methods in the controller class are 'actions'. Hope this helps.